# Firestore - How to handle queries inside an object of document?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have `users` collection. A single document of `users` is built like this:

```
interface User {
  coaching?: {
    sampleOfCoach: Coaching
    anotherSample: Coaching
  }
  displayName: string;
  email: string;
  isCoach: boolean;
  photoURL: string;
  uid: string;
}
```

I want to get only the docs from the `users` collection that has:

- `isCoach: true`
- `coaching.{nameOfCoach}`

Which leads me to another two question.

First, in firebase docs, they recommend to keep the same structures for all of the docs in the same collection. Which means, I should keep the `coaching` property in a non-coach user doc.

Second, On one hand, the `isCoach` property is redundent because I can check if the user is a coach or not depending on the `coaching` property. On the other hand, what if I want to query all of the coaches? is there a query that can check the size of an object?

---

I know there are multiple questions in here, but each question has to do with another question, so I decided to write them in a single question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement to have every document in the collection the same.  If you have some users with coaches and some without, then you can omit the `coaches` object from the document.

In a query, you can only return fields where a value is `>`, `>=`, `==`, `<` or `<=` than a value / string.  There is nothing similar to `isExist` or `count`.  The best option is to have your boolean `isCoach`